# Regular expression to fix double quotes in malformed "JSON" data

Tags: python, json, regex, escaping

I'm on Python 3.7. I need a regular expression to find the start and stop location of "bad values" within double quotes. My JSON looks nearly identical to the following.

```
[
 {
  "key": "test1",
  "value": "<a href="http://something.com">something.com</a>",
 },
 {
  "key": "test2",
  "value": [
   "i have some "double" quotes",
   "<div class="test">some html may exists as well</div>"
  ]
 }, 
 // repeats arbitrary number of times
]
```

As you can see, the problem exists (as far as I can tell) with only the values of the `value` keys. Also, the values of the `value` keys may be a string or array of strings. If I escape the double quotes within the values, I can use Python's `json` module to load the data/string as a dictionary, which is my goal.

Any tips on using regex or any other solution to track the start and stop double quotes and then escape the double quotes within them is appreciated.

For example, I would like a regex to find the following values

- `"<a href="http://something.com">something.com</a>"`
- `"i have some "double" quotes"`
- `"<div class="test">some html may exists as well</div>"`

and replace them as follows

- `"<a href=\"http://something.com\">something.com</a>"`
- `"i have some \"double\" quotes"`
- `"<div class=\"test\">some html may exists as well</div>"`

Comment: I think JSON Parsing can be done with a PDA where regex is FSA compatible. Therefore, you can not, or at least you should not...

Comment: @KemalKaplan What is PDA and FSA?

Comment: They are PushDown Automaton vs Finite State Automaton. There is a nice wiki page about it; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that works specifically for your example:

(*for this code I've stored the JSON in c:\temp\input.json*)

```
import re

f = open(r'c:\temp\input.json', 'r')
lines = f.read()
f.close()

def replace(m):
    return '"' + m.group(1).replace('\"', '\\\"') + '"'

# escape all nested quote characters
lines = '\n'.join([re.sub('\"(.*)\"', replace, line) for line in lines.split('\n')])
        
# the code does some unwanted replacements, like this:
# "key": "test1", ---> "key\": \"test1",
# the next line reverts that
lines = lines.replace('\\\": \\\"', '\": \"')

print(lines)
```

It's not amazing and would need work to handle a more complex input, but hopefully that's useful.