# How to replace double quotes inside single quotes using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

How can I replace double quotes inside single quoted sections with something like `\"`?

Given this text:

```
{['abc.abc',"dsa",asd:'<td id="ssa" width="2px" class="odd-column">']}
```

I want it to be:

```
{['abc.abc',"dsa",asd:'<td id=\"ssa\" width=\"2px\" class=\"odd-column\">']}
```

In a later step I will replace all single quotes to get proper json for convertion.

Comment: [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68638449/3832970) might help, but you will still be quite far from a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a python script which does what you are asking for.
We have to escape all the `"` and `\`

```
import re

string = r"""{['abc.abc',"dsa",asd:'<td id="ssa" width="2px" class="odd-column">']}"""
print(string)
sstring = re.sub(r'\"','\\"',string)
print(sstring)
```

the output is

```
{['abc.abc',\"dsa\",asd:'<td id=\"ssa\" width=\"2px\" class=\"odd-column\">']}
```